# Why was this "vs." question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Decision Tree vs Behavior Tree](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51693/26250)

This is an old question, with highly voted question and answer. It was put on hold as "primarily opinion-based". Although it was inviting a comparison, it wasn't asking for subjective answers like "which one is best", or "which one is better". I think the answer does a great job at sticking to facts, giving an overview of each, and illustrating the pros and cons. It wasn't attracting opinion-based answers or comments.

Why was this one put on hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems I went too fast on that one, sorry about that.

It's reopen now.